# Is all MIPS code on Linux supposed to be PIC?

Tags: linux, assembly, linker, shared-libraries, mips

In Linux on MIPS CPUs (MIPSEL32 to be precise), is it true that all userland SO's are supposed be position independent (PIC)? A cite from an authoritative source would be the the best.

How about Android?

My interest stems from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181640/free-pascal-for-android-on-mips).

Comment: amd64 requires all shared libraries to be PIC. There's no reason to suspect otherwise for MIPS (the rule is probably "when there's enough registers, use PIC").

Comment: MIPS has a dedicated register for global pointer, by convention. Still, a cite would be nice.

Comment: On the other hand, ARM has the same 16 general purpose registers as x86_86 (modulo PC not being exactly general purpose), yet it doesn't require PIC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation with PIC code on Linux appears to be somewhat interesting. In the past (pre EGLIBC-2.9) all binaries on MIPS where supposed to be PIC (both applications and shared libraries). However, to reduce the size of applications, the ABI extension was developed to allow for non-PIC executables (but shared objects stay PIC, as before):

> At this time we do not propose any change to the position-independent
>   addressing conventions used by shared objects. Similarly,
>   position-independent executables compiled with '-fpie' -- as required
>   for address space randomisation in "hardened" Linux distributions --
>   shall continue to use the existing psABI addressing and calling
>   mechanisms.

http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2008-07/txt00000.txt

The wiki page on linux-mips.org stating that all binaries on MIPS must be PIC appears to be somewhat out of date, as both recent GCC and EGLIBC on Linux support non-PIC executables: http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/PIC_code