# What is the name of the default code model used by gcc for MIPS 64?

Tags: assembly, gcc, mips, mips64, compiler-explorer

gcc for MIPS 64 is using a complex method to locate and invoke a function not present in the compilation unit.  What is the name of this code model (and where is it documented)?  I searched but did not find it forthcoming.  It involves `$28`/`$gp` and `$25`/`$t9` as some kind of parameter to pass to the called function.

And, is there a bug in this translation (either in code gen or the textual output)?

The following code sequence:

```
extern int g(int);

int f(int x)
{
    return g(x) + 2;
}
```

generates this output:

```
        daddiu  $sp,$sp,-16
        sd      $28,0($sp)
        lui     $28,%hi(%neg(%gp_rel(f(int))))
        daddu   $28,$28,$25                             <--- sourcing $25/$t9 
        daddiu  $28,$28,%lo(%neg(%gp_rel(f(int))))
        ld      $25,%call16(_Z1gi)($28)
        sd      $31,8($sp)
        nop                       <--- where is the function call??

        ld      $31,8($sp)
        ld      $28,0($sp)
        addiu   $2,$2,2
        j       $31
        daddiu  $sp,$sp,16
```

At my 2nd <-- marker in the above, I would expect to see an indirect function call, but all that's there is a `nop` (which might have been intended for the delay slot of a call instruction, and is otherwise not explainable).

(At my first marker, it sources $25, so that must be a parameter of some kind provided to `f`; `f` appears to also setup $25 maybe for `g` as well.)

---

https://godbolt.org/z/11n9nxs63

Adding `-msym32` to command line options for the above (which tells it to assume all symbols have a 32-bit address), the code uses direct function call via `jal`.

Comment: IIRC, Linux MIPS requires position-independent code, but PC-relative is inefficient on MIPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer, to the "is there a bug" part, not the name of the code-model in the MIPS64 ABI.

Turns out the [compiler-explorer] tag was relevant after all:  It was hiding a

```
1:   jalr   $25
```

before the `nop` (which is indeed in the branch delay slot), which was a target of a `.reloc  1f,R_MIPS_JALR,g` on the previous line.  **[Uncheck "hide unused labels"](https://godbolt.org/z/sbaKKhsxd)**; I guess the filtering incorrectly assumes that labels won't be on the same line as instructions, which isn't the case for MIPS.

So yes, indeed, the this is loading a pointer from the GOT into `$25` and jumping through it.

Apparently with `$25` as the function's own address as part of the ABI/calling convention, to enable position-independent code (which apparently Linux MIPS always requires, even though I thought MIPS couldn't  do that very efficiently until very recent MIPS revisions for `ADDIUPC`.)

Comment: Wow, great info, thanks!  I had wondered if it might be a "textual" problem; wasn't really but something like that (operator (me) error.. ;)

Comment: And Linux ABI for MIPS 64 is close enough for me, thanks.

Comment: @ErikEidt: I didn't actually check the ABI doc; the incoming $25 is just what I'm inferring from *this* code reading $25 without writing it, and calling another function that way.  But I have read before about Linux MIPS using position-independent code.  [Is all MIPS code on Linux supposed to be PIC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20413290) on SO, and https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/PIC_code  (ah, that says "It is currently not possible to mix non-PIC object files and PIC object files when linking." - presumably that's because the PIC ABI includes passing PC in $25, which non-PIC wouldn't.)